# How get current used config on SolrCloud

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

How can I know which configurations is used from my SolrCloud collection?

I know how to upload and link but I also need to know which one is currently used by a collection.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to find out config name:
Cloud -> Tree -> Collections -> Click on collection name.

[image]

Then you can check config:
Cloud -> Tree -> Configs -> Click on config name

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All the config is stored in ZooKeeper, so you can access it via a ZooKeeper client or the SolrJ client.